# <styleSCOPED> ruin my css in my Nuxt js app

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

My problem is quite simple and complicated at the same time, I forked this simple HTML, CSS, JS repo : [Snake game](https://github.com/RabiRoshan/snake_game).
and then I transformed it to a Nuxt Js app : [My repo](https://github.com/Imsenji/Snake-nuxt) .

1. when I use the `Scoped` attribute in my `style` tag , the Js code works fine, but with no pissibility to see the snake :
   [image]
2. When I remove the `Scoped` attribute, The snake goes crazy and ouf of borders, and it ruins the style either :
   [image]

my code :

```js
window.onload = function() {
    // GAME_PIXEL_COUNT is the pixels on horizontal or vertical axis of the game board (SQUARE).
    const GAME_PIXEL_COUNT = 40;
    const SQUARE_OF_GAME_PIXEL_COUNT = Math.pow(GAME_PIXEL_COUNT, 2);

    let totalFoodAte = 0;
    let totalDistanceTravelled = 0;

    /// THE GAME BOARD:
    const gameContainer = document.getElementById("gameContainer");

    const createGameBoardPixels = () => {
        // Populate the [#gameContainer] div with small div's representing game pixels
        for (let i = 1; i <= SQUARE_OF_GAME_PIXEL_COUNT; ++i) {
            gameContainer.innerHTML = `${gameContainer.innerHTML} <div class="gameBoardPixel" id="pixel${i}"></div>`;
        }
    };

    // This variable always holds the updated array of game pixels created by createGameBoardPixels() :
    const gameBoardPixels = document.getElementsByClassName("gameBoardPixel");

    /// THE FOOD:
    let currentFoodPostion = 0;
    const createFood = () => {
        // Remove previous food;
        gameBoardPixels[currentFoodPostion].classList.remove("food");

        // Create new food
        currentFoodPostion = Math.random();
        currentFoodPostion = Math.floor(
            currentFoodPostion * SQUARE_OF_GAME_PIXEL_COUNT
        );
        gameBoardPixels[currentFoodPostion].classList.add("food");
    };

    /// THE SNAKE:

    // Direction codes (Keyboard key codes for arrow keys):
    const LEFT_DIR = 37;
    const UP_DIR = 38;
    const RIGHT_DIR = 39;
    const DOWN_DIR = 40;

    // Set snake direction initially to right
    let snakeCurrentDirection = RIGHT_DIR;

    const changeDirection = (newDirectionCode) => {
        // Change the direction of the snake
        if (newDirectionCode == snakeCurrentDirection) return;

        if (newDirectionCode == LEFT_DIR && snakeCurrentDirection != RIGHT_DIR) {
            snakeCurrentDirection = newDirectionCode;
        } else if (newDirectionCode == UP_DIR && snakeCurrentDirection != DOWN_DIR) {
            snakeCurrentDirection = newDirectionCode;
        } else if (
            newDirectionCode == RIGHT_DIR &&
            snakeCurrentDirection != LEFT_DIR
        ) {
            snakeCurrentDirection = newDirectionCode;
        } else if (newDirectionCode == DOWN_DIR && snakeCurrentDirection != UP_DIR) {
            snakeCurrentDirection = newDirectionCode;
        }
    };

    // Let the starting position of the snake be at the middle of game board
    let currentSnakeHeadPosition = SQUARE_OF_GAME_PIXEL_COUNT / 2;

    // Initial snake length
    let snakeLength = 1000;

    // Move snake continously by calling this function repeatedly :
    const moveSnake = () => {
        switch (snakeCurrentDirection) {
            case LEFT_DIR:
                --currentSnakeHeadPosition;
                const isSnakeHeadAtLastGameBoardPixelTowardsLeft =
                    currentSnakeHeadPosition % GAME_PIXEL_COUNT == GAME_PIXEL_COUNT - 1 ||
                    currentSnakeHeadPosition < 0;
                if (isSnakeHeadAtLastGameBoardPixelTowardsLeft) {
                    currentSnakeHeadPosition = currentSnakeHeadPosition + GAME_PIXEL_COUNT;
                }
                break;
            case UP_DIR:
                currentSnakeHeadPosition = currentSnakeHeadPosition - GAME_PIXEL_COUNT;
                const isSnakeHeadAtLastGameBoardPixelTowardsUp =
                    currentSnakeHeadPosition < 0;
                if (isSnakeHeadAtLastGameBoardPixelTowardsUp) {
                    currentSnakeHeadPosition =
                        currentSnakeHeadPosition + SQUARE_OF_GAME_PIXEL_COUNT;
                }
                break;
            case RIGHT_DIR:
                ++currentSnakeHeadPosition;
                const isSnakeHeadAtLastGameBoardPixelTowardsRight =
                    currentSnakeHeadPosition % GAME_PIXEL_COUNT == 0;
                if (isSnakeHeadAtLastGameBoardPixelTowardsRight) {
                    currentSnakeHeadPosition = currentSnakeHeadPosition - GAME_PIXEL_COUNT;
                }
                break;
            case DOWN_DIR:
                currentSnakeHeadPosition = currentSnakeHeadPosition + GAME_PIXEL_COUNT;
                const isSnakeHeadAtLastGameBoardPixelTowardsDown =
                    currentSnakeHeadPosition > SQUARE_OF_GAME_PIXEL_COUNT - 1;
                if (isSnakeHeadAtLastGameBoardPixelTowardsDown) {
                    currentSnakeHeadPosition =
                        currentSnakeHeadPosition - SQUARE_OF_GAME_PIXEL_COUNT;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        let nextSnakeHeadPixel = gameBoardPixels[currentSnakeHeadPosition];

        // Kill snake if it bites itself:
        if (nextSnakeHeadPixel.classList.contains("snakeBodyPixel")) {
            // Stop moving the snake
            clearInterval(moveSnakeInterval);
            if (!alert(
                    `You have ate ${totalFoodAte} food by travelling ${totalDistanceTravelled} blocks.`
                ))
                window.location.reload();
        }

        nextSnakeHeadPixel.classList.add("snakeBodyPixel");

        setTimeout(() => {
            nextSnakeHeadPixel.classList.remove("snakeBodyPixel");
        }, snakeLength);

        // Update total distance travelled
        totalDistanceTravelled++;
        // Update in UI:
        document.getElementById("blocksTravelled").innerHTML = totalDistanceTravelled;

        if (currentSnakeHeadPosition == currentFoodPostion) {
            // Update total food ate
            totalFoodAte++;
            // Update in UI:
            document.getElementById("pointsEarned").innerHTML = totalFoodAte;

            // Increase Snake length:
            snakeLength = snakeLength + 100;
            createFood();
        }
    };

    /// CALL THE FOLLOWING FUNCTIONS TO RUN THE GAME:

    // Create game board pixels:
    createGameBoardPixels();

    // Create initial food:
    createFood();

    // Move snake:
    var moveSnakeInterval = setInterval(moveSnake, 80);

    // Call change direction function on keyboard key-down event:
    addEventListener("keydown", (e) => changeDirection(e.keyCode));

    // ON SCREEN CONTROLLERS:
    const leftButton = document.getElementById("leftButton");
    const rightButton = document.getElementById("rightButton");
    const upButton = document.getElementById("upButton");
    const downButton = document.getElementById("downButton");

    leftButton.onclick = () => changeDirection(LEFT_DIR);
    rightButton.onclick = () => changeDirection(RIGHT_DIR);
    upButton.onclick = () => changeDirection(UP_DIR);
    downButton.onclick = () => changeDirection(DOWN_DIR);
}
```

```css
<style scoped>
 body {
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    text-align: center;
}


/* GAME BOARD STYLES */

#gameContainer {
    /*
    width and height of .gameBoardPixel should 1/40 of the width and height of #gameContainer,
    because it is used in calculation in the jscript.js file
    */
    width: 40vw;
    height: 40vw;
    margin: 2vw auto;
    background-color: #0c1021;
    border: solid 10px slategrey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.gameBoardPixel {
    /* background-color: slategrey; */
    /*
    width and height of .gameBoardPixel should 1/40 of the width and height of #gameContainer,
    because it is used in calculation in the jscript.js file
    */
    width: 1vw;
    height: 1vw;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
}


/* GAME BOARD STYLES END*/


/* SNAKE STYLES */

.snakeBodyPixel {
    background-color: #fd6401;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fd6401;
}


/* SNAKE STYLES END*/


/* FOOD STYLES */

.food {
    background-color: #68e768;
}


/* FOOD STYLES END*/


/* SCORE STYLES */

#scoreContainer {
    width: 40vw;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.scoreBoard {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 5px slategrey;
    color: dimgray;
    background-color: #0c1021;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1vw;
    width: 40%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}


/* SCORE STYLES END */


/* Hide #onScreenControllers on desktop */

#onScreenControllers {
    display: none;
}

.developerDetails {
    margin-top: 2vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #0c1021;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.developerDetails a {
    color: #0c1021;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* MOBILE */
    #gameContainer {
        width: 80vw;
        height: 80vw;
    }
    .gameBoardPixel {
        width: 2vw;
        height: 2vw;
    }
    #scoreContainer {
        width: 80vw;
    }
    #onScreenControllers {
        width: 80vw;
        margin: 5vw auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
    }
    #onScreenControllers>div {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    #onScreenControllers button {
        background-color: transparent;
        height: 20vw;
        width: 20vw;
        font-size: 10vw;
        border: none;
    }
    #onScreenControllers button:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
    #onScreenControllers button:active {
        background-color: slategray;
    }
}
</style>
```

```html
<template>
<body>
<div>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Snake v8</title>
    
   
 
 
    <!-- #gameContainer is the main game board-->
   
    <div id="gameContainer"></div>
   
    
    
    <!-- #scoreContainer contains the scores  -->
    <div id="scoreContainer">
      <div class="scoreBoard">Food: <span id="pointsEarned">0</span></div>
      <div class="scoreBoard">Blocks: <span id="blocksTravelled">0</span></div>
    </div>

    <!-- #onScreenControllers contains the navigation buttons for mobile screens -->
    <div id="onScreenControllers">
      <button id="leftButton">◀️</button>
      <div>
        <button id="upButton"></button>
        <button id="downButton"></button>
      </div>
      <button id="rightButton">▶️</button>
    </div>

    

</div>
</body>

</template>
```

Any help please ? thank you

Comment: The most obvious reason is that you use selectors to access DOM. This will surely fail because `scoped` does everything to prevent this. You have to avoid this, this is not how Vue components are written.

Comment: Thank you for your response ! do you think thi can be solved by using deep selectors ?

Comment: I doubt that. This can be done by rewritting the script to proper Vue code. It doesn't make sense to wrap plain JS with Vue/Nuxt, you will fight the framework and won't have any benefits they provide. And it doesn't make much sense to use Nuxt for browser game in general because there's nothing to render on server site.

Comment: Also, not sure what you expect from us here besides debugging it for you. You can pretty much open the devtools inspector and find out why the CSS is not applied to your liking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found  where the problem is :

in my Nuxt.js app, im using `Tailwind`, and it applies a default style to all my `<div>` tags .

the solution was to add this to my global CSS :

```
*
{
box-sizing: initial;
}
```